# Very slow web server connection from outside my LAN

Tags: networking, router, dns, connection

I recently (~2 months ago) changed IP address for my main web server and I have extremely slow connect/response time to the server from the outside world. It will eventually connect, but takes as much as 5 minutes.

I have checked the A/AAAA record and it points to the correct IP address. I am forwarding port 80 both TCP and UDP to the server through my router and I have checked the response after disabling the firewall with no improvement.

I have tried to ping the server from outside and it says there is an error, but no other information.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting when you ping it? Also, how did you change your server IP? If you are able to request an IP change I would try changing it again and seeing if it resolves the issue. You may be having an IP conflict with another internet device - I had an issue with having a conflicting IP assigned to my house by my ISP one time which had similar symptoms.

Comment: If this was a DNS change, it may take some time to propagate. You should have patience.

Comment: Did you change the NAT private IPv4 address of your web server, or the public IPv4 address of your NAT gateway? Or both? Also, what changes did you make with respect to IPv6 addresses (since you mention that you have a AAAA record for this hostname)?

Comment: if you connect to it externally by IP, how well does it work?